# Javacsript + Android Webview: click button programmatically

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am writing an Android App. The App opens a website in Webview.
The website shows a rating bar, i.e. a rating bar that consists of 5 stars (i.e. buttons) to click on, but I want to click the stars programmatically from the app.

From the developer console in Chrome I got the javascript code of that website.
This is the javascript code for the first star of the ratinbgbar:

```
<div class="ratingbar-container" steps="5">
  <div class="ratingbar-wrap" style="height: 40px; font-size: 38px;">
    <div class="rating" rel="1">
       <i class="svi-star ratingicon-full"></i>
       <i class="svi-star-o ratingicon-outline">
       </i>
    </div>
    <div class="rating" rel="2">
```

Now I want my App to click the star programmatically.
In the code below I tried to click the first star programmtaically like this but nothing happens:

```
wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {          
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequestrequest) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());                               
        String jsclick = "javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('rating')[0].click();";
        view.loadUrl(jsclick);

        return false;
    }           
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: NullPointerException. the DOM is loaded first?

Comment: yes, ```document.getElementsByClassName('rating')``` does  not return null.

Comment: if it's not null then bind a click event to the button.

Comment: No a click event doesn't help me here since my question is how to TRIGGER the click.

Comment: which is the element that you have bind the click event?

Comment: It's not my website, I want my App to click for me, The App shall execute ```click()``` on the ``` <i>``` element.

Comment: the element is button, image?

Comment: Yes. It is a website from a company with a rating bar, and I want to click on the stars (buttons) of the rating bar.

Comment: ok `$("#button_id").click()`

Comment: but what is the button_id in this case? The javascript code is in my entry post.

Comment: the element id or class and then trigger click

Comment: thanks a a lot i will try again!

Answer (score -1):

You need an event listener on the clicks

```js
let ratings = document.querySelectorAll(".rating");
forof(const rating of ratings){
    rating.addEventListener('click',function(e){
      //Whatever code you want to run
    }
}
```