# Must a button have a button tag?

Tags: javascript

In the code below is a website with a star rating bar. Stars can be clicked. But when I open the chrome developer console to see the javascript code, there are no button tags. Are the 5 stars considered buttons?
Isn't there supposed to be a click event listener?
When I click on a star it turns blue. How can this work?

And which part of the code is exactly the button? Is it this line?

```
<i class="svi-star ratingicon-full"></i>
```

```
<div class="subject-answer">
  <div class="ratingbar-container" steps="5">
    <div class="ratingbar-wrap" style="height: 40px; font-size: 38px;">
      <div class="rating" rel="1">
        <i class="svi-star ratingicon-full"></i>
        <i class="svi-star-o ratingicon-outline">
        </i>
      </div>
      <div class="rating" rel="2">
      <div class="rating" rel="3">
      <div class="rating" rel="4">
      <div class="rating" rel="5">
      </div>
    <div class="input-wrapper">...</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

(I just can not copy and paste, I have to buy another coffee first to get a new code to be able to open this website, but I hope the code part I just typed is enough for now)

On the left is the webpage with the rating bar, on the right is the corresponding javascript code (chrome dev console):

![on the left is the webpage with the rating bar, on the right is the corresponding javacode (chrome dev console)][1]

Comment: just add the `onClick` property to the tag

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski That's not what his question is about.

Comment: It's not my website. I am trying to understand why this works.

Comment: @Rob ok I will type the code.

Answer (score 0):

every HTML element can have an event listener called onClick, it can be a `<div>` that you can click, it can be `<span>`, in this case, it's a `<i>`.
Everything is normal don't worry ;)

Make sure to add the css {cursor: pointer;} so when you hover it will show the hand :)

Comment for more UX questions.

Comment: Every element **can** have an event listener but it's not there unless one assigns it using code.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know how to programmtically click that ```<i>```? I tam writing an Android App, and I want the App to click the stars for me. I tried but it dowsn't work.

Comment: It's actually my other question here.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051826/javacsript-android-webview-click-button-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can have click event on every html element there is. Therefore anything can be a button.

```js
document.querySelector('.div').onclick = () => {
  console.log('clicked on a div');
}

document.querySelector('.span').onclick = () => {
  console.log('clicked on a span');
}
```

```css
.div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.span {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <span class="span">this is a clickable span</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes,but above there is no ```onclick``` and yet it works, that's what I don't understand.

Comment: it's probably in a seperate Javascript file, just like in this snippet.

Comment: ok thanks. Do you hapenn to know if Is it possible to see such an seperate file with the chrome developer console?

Comment: Yes, in the source tab, you will see every file loading when you open the site. I can't tell you exactly where it is, but it must be there. It also might be in a minified file, so there is a chance it's going to be hard to find. @user12432260

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create things which are not buttons which can still be clicked (any element can have a *click* event listener added to it), and in this case, it appears that the website has some italic elements with no contents and some styling with such associated JavaScript.

*Best practice* is to use semantic HTML which, in this case, would be `<button>` elements (or possibly `<input type="radio">`) as these come with all sorts of affordances (which are particularly useful for accessibility purposes as they allow, for example, an arthritic user who can't operate a mouse to navigate with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key or a blind user to access the content with a screen reader).

Note that depending on your geographical location, your audience's geographical location, and the type of service your website offers: You may be legally required to ensure it is accessible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: Do you happen to know in this case  how to programmatically click the first star (button)? I have asked the question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051826/javacsript-android-webview-click-button-programmatically